# What should be synchronized with Java objects

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

Say you have 2 or more threads which share an object A.

object A has a list inside of it, which contains another object B

Object A
    List
         Object B

Now the threads modify/read Object B

Question is, what should be synchronized?
Object A as they both access it, or Object B since that's what they read/modify

I cannot seem to find the answer to my question anywhere.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Going a simplest and safest route, you need to synchronize on the outmost object in your object hierarchy, which should be operated in a atomic manner.

In your example, it seems like you need to synchronize on *a list* (unfortunately, I can't be sure what's really you going to do without actual code).

Here's sample code:

```
class B {
}

class A {
    private final List<B> listOfBs = new ArrayList<B>();

    void add(B b) {
        synchronized (listOfBs) {
            listOfBs.add(b);
        }
    }

    List<B> getSnapshot() {
        List<B> copy = new ArrayList<B>();
        synchronized (listOfBs) {
            copy.addAll(listOfBs);
        }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Please, note that you need to declare list as `final` to eliminate possibility that some code may change reference to a list which violate atomicity:

```
    // will make add() and getSnapshot() not mutually exclusive, thus violating atomicity of operations 
    ...
    listOfBs = new ArrayList<B>();
    ...
```

Reading [Java concurrent programming tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) will help.

Comment: this code is _not_ thread-safe, as wrapping listOfBs with an unmodifiable wrapper does _not_ make the result of getSnapshot() thread-safe.  (since a caller to add() can modify the listOfBs which is being referenced by the unmodifiable wrapper).  to make this code thread-safe, you must do something like _copy_ the list before wrapping or use a thread-safe collection implementation.

Comment: In `getSnapshot()` only `copy.addAll(listOfBs);` needs to be in the synchronized block. It's best to limit the scope of synchronized.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot
The part that I was confused with:
Could there be any problems with the fact that 2+ threads are accessing Object A?

Comment: @Remco no, once your code works for 2 threads *always*, it will work for any number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify object B through one of its methods, then you should make that method (or the part that does the writing) synchronized.